# I get an error when I try to move a Wordpress site for development

Tags: wordpress

I am re-designing someone's Wordpress website and moslty need to change the CSS I wanted to move the entire website over to my server in order to develop it.  Mostly I am just changing the design/CSS but there are some custom parts I want to keep such as there is a testimonial plug-in/widget that has a custom place in the dashboard and a way to post testimonials.
I downloaded the entire site.
Exported the database
And then moved it to my server and uploaded the files and created a new database and imported it.

Then I used this to change the database to the correct directory:
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
Now I am getting a crazy error:

**Warning:** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home//public_html/wordpress/wp-config.php:156) in /home/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-greet-box/includes/wp-greet-box.class.php on line 493

**Warning:** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/llhimhi1/public_html/wordpress/wp-config.php:156) in /home/l/public_html/a/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121

I don't know if I should continue trying to make this work, or just copy the theme to a fresh install.  But I am not sure what else to copy since there are custom plugins and stuff in the dashboard.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you update DB user and Pass in wp-config.php?

Comment: did you update DB user and Pass in wp-config.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "headers already sent" error is a very common PHP error having to do with white space or junk characters in a file, or a file that was corrupted during FTP transfer. Check your wp-config.php file.

From [FAQ Troubleshooting » Headers already sent warning « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F)

> It is usually because there are spaces, new lines, or other stuff
>   before an opening  tag, typically in
>   wp-config.php. This could be true about some other file too, so please
>   check the error message, as it will list the specific file name where
>   the error occurred (see "Interpreting the Error Message" below).
>   Replacing the faulty file with one from your most recent backup or one
>   from a fresh WordPress download is your best bet, but if neither of
>   those are an option, please follow the steps (at the link above).

And read http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress on how to set up debugging to find causes of "white pages" and other PHP errors.

Comment: this worked thank you so much, but now the home page shows up but not the other pages, is this a database problem?